# Assigning a value to value of a parameter in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, parameters

Consider the below variables in shell:

```
$ a=b  
$ c=d
```

Now i need to store **d**(value of c) in **b**(value of a).

```
$ $a=$c
```

This throws error: `-sh: b=d: command not found`

How will I achieve this?

Comment: Why do not direcctly do `b=$c`?

Comment: Value of a is dynamic

Comment: Why are you writing shell code that stores variables names in other variables in the first place? That's typically a sign you should be using another language.

Answer (score 0):

Using `declare`:

```
$ a=b  
$ c=d
$ declare $a=$c
$ echo $b
d
```

Comment: Do you really want to `eval` variables `a` like `echo Hello` and `rm ~brown/* `?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill variables with `printf`. When you don't know the content of `$c`, using `%s` is a safe way avoiding special characters.

```
printf -v $a "%s" "$c"
```